# How should my Azure web role react to invalid settings being fed on configuration change?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles

I have an Azure web role which has some settings defined in the service configuration (.cscfg file). Suppose there's a setting that denotes a boolean and so in my code I will retrieve the string and convert in to `bool` C# type - using `bool.Parse()` or `bool.TryParse()`.

Suppose the service starts with a valid configuration and then some time later the configuration is changed through Management Portal and the person doing so mistypes the string and types `fasle` instead of `false` and submits the new configuration without noticing.

Azure runtime cannot care less - all the settings are strings and `fasle` is a no less valid string than `false`. Yet the code trying to convert this string into a boolean will not be able to do so.

How should the web role code deal with such situations?

Answer (score 0):

Assume a safe default value for each configuration element and then use the TryParse or equivalent methods in a custom library you write to expose your configuration items to the rest of your application.  Always design with a "fail safe" mentality (this may include making the application display an error to the user that it is unavailable where there is no real "fail safe" option).

Comment: Well, okay, the code won't break hard but how should it signal that the configuration is invalid and must be fixed?

Comment: That's up to you :). Email it to the admin, display an icon the website, I'm not sure - the choice is yours.  The only thing I'd avoid would be the reporting being driven by the configuration that can be broken :).

Comment: So there's no way to report the problem back to the portal and make it display some reasonable diagnostic message, is there?

Comment: You could write to the Azure Diagnostics service (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/).  I don't think they're at the point where you can expose custom metrics - if you could then you could write a custom performance counter that would expose this issue if it existed.